# How to force Icecast to list one mount on YP Directory?

Tags: linux, icecast

I have 3 mounts (A, B and C), I can hide or publish those mounts using `<public></public>` or `<hidden></hidden>`.

The problem, When i publish thos mounts, i see my 3 mounts on YP directory.

I tryed to hide B and C, then i published A, but i see only the listeners of A.

How to force showing the listeners of B and C on the published mount (A) ?

They are all in one server (CentOS). Icecast version : 2.4.3

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Icecast publishes the numbers *for the mountpoint that it's advertizing* to a YP server. You can't make it lie about the numbers. So what you are asking for is impossible.

Are those other mount points (`B` and `C`) fallbacks to A or are they independent? If yes, then that's a *different* problem and there is a solution to that.

Comment: I need different bitrates, to allow who has a bad connection to listen to my station (A: 128 - B: 64 - C: 192). So they are independants (3 encoders). Someone told me that there's a way to force showing one mount with all listeners but he lost the tuto.

Comment: That would make for rather bad experience for listeners coming in through the directory because they will be on a *random* mountpoint, consequentially *random* quality. If that is *really* what you want, then you can configure a common `<cluster-password>` in each `<mount>` section. All mounts *MUST* be public and listing for this to work! As the cluster-password is *directory* global, you better use a LONG (>16 characters) and random string, else you might end up sharing the listing with some other stream that also used "hackme" or such!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, before trying the cluster password, can you please give me more info "you better use a LONG (>16 characters) and random string, else you might end up sharing the listing with some other stream that also used "hackme" or such!" ?

Comment: A random string ?

Comment: "Password" is really a misnomer, while it should be kept secret (with it everyone can have their stream listed as part of your listing). It should be a GUID https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier to be safe for use.

Comment: I added "<cluster-password>key</cluster-password>" (the same key) and set <public>1</public> on my 3 mounts. restarted icecast, i checked http://dir.xiph.org i see my 3 mounts.

Comment: Please check http://dir.xiph.org/search?search=TestComS1 you willl see my 3 mounts. Isn't there a way to show only one mount with the number of all listeners ?

Comment: Hmm, looks like the old YP code doesn't support this properly. The new one (soon to be rolled out) should. Sorry.

Comment: That's fine,thanks for your replies, a last question about the sound quality, because some people in africa got disconnected when they connect to 128 bitrate. you said : "That would make for rather bad experience for listeners". They (people in africa) do need 64 to listen, however people in France may connect to 192 or at least 128. How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: I would do this by listing the three quality levels separately on YP and also making sure that they are named in a way that indicates either bandwidth or quality or both.

Comment: Done, thanks for your advices. When the new one will be rolled out ? Where to check the updates ? because i don't like to keep showing 3 Mounts in the YP.